# ng-bootstrap click handler not working in dropdown

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I have a a button dropdown menu which I have directly copied from [this ng-bootstrap example](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown/examples).

The dropdown works but if add a click handler to the dropdown buttons as follows, it doesn't fire when the button is clicked:

```html
    <div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dropdownBasic1" ngbDropdownToggle>Toggle dropdown</button>
      <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1">
        <button ngbDropdownItem click="clicked()">Not Me</button>
        <button ngbDropdownItem click="clicked()">Me neither</button>
        <button ngbDropdownItem click="clicked()">Nor me</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here is a [Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c6agv9) forked from the original example.

Am I doing something really stupid? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`click` should be surrounded by brackets:

```
<div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dropdownBasic1" ngbDropdownToggle>Toggle dropdown</button>
  <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1">
    <button ngbDropdownItem (click)="clicked()">Not Me</button>
    <button ngbDropdownItem (click)="clicked()">Me neither</button>
    <button ngbDropdownItem (click)="clicked()">Nor me</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also make sure you have implemented method `clicked()` in your component

Comment: Thanks, damn I *did* do something stupid - thanks for answering. In my original code I didn't miss the brackets though and it's still not firing.